# Pattern for this programming task (PHP)?

Tags: php, function, design-patterns

I have some functions which share lots of code. Some code however differs for each method and cant be encapsulated. This is an example:

```
public function function1(){
    same code
    same code1
    this differs
    same code2
    this differs
    same code 3
}

public function function2(){
    same code
    same code1
    this differs
    this differs
    same code 3
}
```

So my idea was to extract the code that is the same to some other functions which I call in each of my functions. Is there a better way of solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: How could there be a better way?

Comment: I dont know, thats why I am asking :).

Comment: Even if there would be, you should first of all remove duplicate code. Key point number one. You can continue refactoring later if you still need to.

Answer (score 1):

First step: Move duplicate code into functions of it's own:

```
public function function1(){
    $this->sameCodeCode1();
    this differs
    same code2
    this differs
    $this->sameCode3();
}

public function function2(){
    $this->sameCodeCode1();
    this differs
    this differs
    $this->sameCode3();
}
```

Then iterate again over it, as it can be seen that what you called *same code2*  is as well the difference:

```
public function function1() {
    $this->inverse(function() {
        this differs
        same code2
        this differs
    });
}

public function function2(){
    $this->inverse(function() {        
        this differs
        this differs
    }
}

private function inverse($function)
{
    same code
    same code1
    $function();
    same code 3
}
```

This might then lead you to further improvements you can do with your code, like creating Method Objects instead of functions that share base classes. See as well the following refactoring pattern: [Replace Method with Method Object](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html).

Answer (score 0):

Function is set of code which dose a specific task. If you use same code you can put that  into several common functions and call them at relevant point . If that not the case you can use include statements which are in separate common files.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the process should be loosen

```
$task1 = new Task ( array (
        "code",
        "code1",
        "differs",
        "code2",
        "code3",
        function () {
            echo "Sample Function";
        } 
) );

$task2 = new Task ( array (
        "code",
        "code1",
        "differs",
        "differs",
        "code3",
        array (
                "Code2,Code4" 
        ) 
) );

echo "<pre />";
$process = new Process ( $task1 );
$process->run ();

echo PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

$process = new Process ( $task2 );
$process->run ();
```

Class

```
class Task {
    private $process = array ();
    function __construct($process) {
        $this->process = $process;
    }

    function add($name) {
        $this->process [] = $name;
    }

    function getProcess($i = null) {
        return ($i == null) ? $this->process : $this->process [$i];
    }

    function getTotal() {
        return count ( $this->process );
    }

}

class Process {
    private $task;
    function __construct(Task $task) {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    function run() {

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->task->getTotal (); $i ++) {
            $run = $this->task->getProcess ( $i );
            if (is_callable ( $run )) {
                $run ();
            } else if (is_string ( $run )) {
                echo "Running " . $run, PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Running code1
Running differs
Running code2
Running code3
Sample Function

Running code1
Running differs
Running differs
Running code3
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a candidate for the Strategy Pattern.

```
public function coreProcess(uniquePart $unique){
    same code
    same code1
    $unique->part1();
    $unique->part2();
    $unique->part3();
    same code 3
}

interface uniquePart
{
  function part1();

  function part2();

  function part3();
}

class process1 implements uniquePart
{
  function part1()
  {
     //some unique code
  }

  function part2()
  {
     //do nothing
  }

  function part3()
  {
    //unique code
  }
}  

class process2 implements uniquePart
{
  function part1()
  {
    //some unique code
  }

  function part2()
  {
     //some unique code
  }

  function part3()
  {
    //some unique code
  }
}

//run process 1
coreProcess(new process1);

//run process 2
coreProcess(new process2);
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/